# How can I pass formvalues to controller in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

When I try to pass value of FormPanel to controller, I get error message.

"Object #< HTMLFormElement> has no method 'getValues' "

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginPage', {
extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',
id: 'loginPanel',
standardSubmit: true,
config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'name',
                    label: 'Kullanıcı Adı'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    name: 'password',
                    label: 'Şifre'
                }
```

How can i access loginPanel.getValues() in controller object?

Comment: When I use Ext.getCmp('loginPanel').getValues(), the problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use Ext.getCmp('loginPanel').getValues(), the problem solved.